Using NFC without using NDEFReader
I am trying to build a Amiibo read-only game support for my phone, but the NDEFReaader is only supported in two different browsers that I don't and can't have. MDN Doc page.
So my question is how can I read NFC tags using something other than NDEFReader? I'm using a Vite server, so I'm able to use libraries.

So you are using an apple device?

Yes. I know it has an NFC touch point because you can put two iPhones together and transfer items to one another.

I have been recommended Amiibox, but I'm not sure if that will work on my project, since my game is in javascript, and Amiibox is an app.

@Zibelas I forgot to at you. I'm still hoping to get this answered soon.

I do not really have experiance with apple development; thats why I asked if it is for apple since Chrome and WebView Android support NDEFReader. But you could use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc
